# Can a JUnit testmethod have a argument?

Tags: java, junit

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestUI {
    private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9()+-]+$");

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        // Test case1
        String[] str=test();

        System.out.println(str[0]+str.length);
        match("Alphanumeric(Text)");
    }

    private static String[] test() {

        boolean res;
        String[] array={"a","b","c","d","e"};
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(match(array[i]));
            res=match(array[i]);
            if(res=true)
                calltomethod(array);
        }

        return array;   
    }

    private static boolean match(String s) {
        return p.matcher(s).matches();
    }

}
```

In the above code I need to pass the array as a argument to a JUnit method, the above code will be present in a JUnit class, can I have these kind of methods in a JUnit class and a test =method with argument?

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at parameterized unit tests (introduced in JUnit 4).

[Daniel Mayer's blog](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/writing-a-parameterized-junit-test/) has an example of this.

Another, more simple example is on [mkyong's webpage](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can with the `Theories` Runner in JUnit 4.4

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheorieTest {

   @DataPoints
   public static String[] strings={"a","b","c","d","e"};

   private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z0-9()+-]+$");

   @Theory
   public void stringTest(String x) {
      assertTrue("string " + x + " should match but does not", p.matcher(x).matches());

   }
 }
```

For more details:

- [Junit 4.4 Release Notes](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/ReleaseNotes4.4.html)
- [Blog](http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/agile-development/test-driven-development/using-junit-datapoints-and-theories/)

Answer (score 5):

yes, it can. recently i started [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) project. it lets you write:

```
@TestWith({
   "25 USD",
   "38 GBP",
   "null"
})
public void testMethod(Money money) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly pass parameters to test methods with JUnit. [TestNG](http://testng.org) allows it, though:

```
//This method will provide data to any test method that declares that its Data
// Provider is named "test1"
@DataProvider(name = "test1")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "Cedric", new Integer(36) },
   { "Anne", new Integer(37)},
 };
}

//This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
//named "test1"
@Test(dataProvider = "test1")
public void verifyData1(String n1, Integer n2) {
 System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2);
}
```

will print:

```
Cedric 36
Anne 37
```

Comment: What is this dataProvider  ? is it the name of xml file or what ?

Comment: JUnit does have this feature. See other answers.

Comment: TestNG way of doing this is a lot better. It is the main thing I miss since I moved from TestNG to JUnit.