# Mocking parameterized constructor using junit

Tags: java, jmockit

I need to construct a test case for a method which needs an instance of SomeClass as below:

```
    class ClassToTest {
         ...
         ...
         public boolean testMethod (SomeClass instance) {
          ....
         }
       ...
    }
    ...
```

SomeClass has parameterized constructors that contain objects of user-defined different classes as well as basic data types like int,float etc..

```
    Class SomeClass {
          ...
          SomeClass(MyClass1 a1, MyClass2 a2,.. String s, int i) {
              //initialize to instance variables (this.a1 = a1;) 
          }
    }
```

How do I get an instance of SomeClass for my test cases?

Comment: does this help you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234339/can-a-junit-testmethod-have-a-argument

Comment: @M.Faizal Thanks.. could you please look at this question too? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058636/null-pointer-exception-in-mocking-interface-method)

Comment: Did you try declaring a `@Mocked SomeClass mock` field or test method parameter in your test? It should provide the desired mocked instance.

Comment: @Rogério yes, I did.. Thanks for telling me that.. I got it now