# Set a static member in main method and access in a Junit Method

Tags: java, junit, command-line-arguments

```
public class A {
   private static String var;
   public static void main(String []args) {
      var = args[0];
      System.out.println(var);  //1
      JunitCore.main("path.A");
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
       System.out.println(var);  //2
   }
}
```

I have code something similar to above. I expect the value passed through commandline to be printed in `1` and `2` cases. But for `2` `null` is being printed even though I have set the variable in the main method. Why is this happening and what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: A main method isn't called in a JUnit test. See also [stackoverflow.com/questions/2884163/… [1]: stackoverflow.com/questions/2884163/…

Comment: @laune I'm running this program as a java application. So the execution starts at `main`

Comment: @boxed__l I want the variable to have the value passed from the command line.

Comment: @Alex Take a look at this SO Question. [JUnit Test Method with Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234339/can-a-junit-testmethod-have-a-argument)

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line of your main method to:

```
JUnitCore.runClasses(A.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that this code works as expected.

```
$ ls path/
A.class
$ echo $CLASSPATH 
.:/extra/JUnit/junit-4.12.jar:/extra/JUnit/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
$ java path.A xyz
from main: xyz
JUnit version 4.12
.xyz
Time: 0.003
OK (1 test)
```

Only changes made were

```
package path;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.*;
```

The proposed

```
JUnitCore.runClasses(A.class);
```

also produces the second println, but method test isn't run as a JUnit Test.