# Using Parameterized JUNIT integrating with Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection, jmeter

Long story short, I have a JUNIT test which I want to integrate it with JMeter. The scripts are written by Selenium WebDriver integrated with Cucumber.

This is my main method,

```
public class SanityStart extends ClassUtility {
    private ClassUtility driver;
    private ClassUtility environment;
    private ClassUtility path;
    private ClassUtility userName;

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SanityStart.class.getName());

    public SanityStart(ClassUtility driver, ClassUtility environment, ClassUtility path, ClassUtility userName) {

        this.driver = driver;
        this.environment = environment;
        this.path=path;
        this.userName=userName;
    }

    @Test
    public void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        environment.environmentValue = args[0];
        path.pathValue = "@" +args[1];
        userName.superUser = args[2];
        System.setProperty("userName",userName.superUser);
        Main.main(new String[]{"-g", "bell.canada.step.definition", "-t", pathValue,  "C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Documents/Automation/Cr Automation/CR Automation/src/NewFeature.feature"});   
    }
}
```

Since I want to re-use the variable I have create a ClassUtility which contains the dependency Injector variables.

```
public class ClassUtility {

    public WebDriver baseDriver;
    public String orderNo;
    public String pageIn;
    public String environmentValue;
    public String pathValue;
    public String superUser;
    public String profile1;
    public String profile2;

}
```

I need to get the values such as environment, path and userName in runtime from JMeter. So that based on the request it will invoke multiple threads and do load testing.

When I try to run as JUNIT test, I'm getting the following error,

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
>   java.lang.Exception: Method main should have no parameters

Need your suggestions/feedback on how I can achieve this! Is it even possible to have a main method in JUNIT test? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also Why am i getting, "Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor ". Does this mean I cannot have a constructor with dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

> Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor

This exception tells you that `SanityStart` constructor should not have any arguments. You only can use them if you are using using [@Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests) or some custom test runner.

> Method main should have no parameters

This tells you that you cannot use `@Test` annotation for function with parameters in JUnit. So `main` cannot be subject of test. Either test an argument-less function, or use some non-standard runner (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234339/can-a-junit-testmethod-have-a-argument)).