# why does junit say my test method should have no parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I have this test method:

```
@Test
    `public void addNumber (int a, int b){`
        `int c= a+b;`
      }
```

And when I run it, I get initialization Error & this exception:

```
"java.lang.Exception: **Method addNumber should have no parameters**"!
```

the question is why my test method should have no parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a JUnit testmethod have a argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234339/can-a-junit-testmethod-have-a-argument)

Comment: As to the question: put yourself in the shoes of JUnit: you have tests to execute. One of them expects two integers. Which values should you pass as argument, and why? Suppose your method expects a Car, a Socket and a URL: what do you pass as argument and why?

Comment: Beyond that: dont put more information into comments, or comments to answers. Make sure your question contains a [mcve] - all the information we need to really help you!

Answer (score 1):

That is junit test method syntax requirement. The test method should not have any parameters.

If you want to use the method with parameters, you can use Data Providers. Download necessary libraries and Annotate the class with @RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class).

Then create data providers:

```
  @DataProvider
  public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
    return new Object[][] {
      {1,2},
      {3,4}
    };
  }
```

And write your junit like this:

```
  @Test
  @UseDataProvider("dataProviderMethod")
  public void addNumber (int a, int b) { 
      int c= a+b;
  }
```

Comment: my project is spring MVC based & it doesn't help me! I get that Exception again!

Comment: I get this new Exception: No valid dataprovider found for test 'addNumber' using the default resolver. By convention the dataprovider method name must either be equal to the test methods name, have a certain replaced or additional prefix (see JavaDoc of class com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.internal.DefaultDataProviderMethodResolver or is explicitely set by @UseDataProvider#value()

Comment: Please check that the data provider method name and the value in @UseDataProvider annotation should be same. For above example it is 'dataProviderMethod'

Answer (score 0):

Or it is possible to use `@Parameters` annotation

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class Test {
    @Test
    @Parameters({"1|2|3", "3|4|7"})
    public void addNumberTest(int a, int b, int sum) {
        assertThat(a + b, is(sum));
    }
}
```